# R highcharter scatter plot legend color is not mapped correctly from the point color as costume palette

Tags: r, highcharts, scatter-plot, r-highcharter

I'm trying to draw a scatter plot with a costume color map. So I define my costume color based on the unique values of a data frame column.

```
library('dplyr')
library('leaflet')
library('highcharter')

n <- length(unique(mtcars$carb))

col_vector <- c('#e6194b', '#3cb44b', '#ffe119', '#4363d8', '#f58231', '#911eb4',
                '#46f0f0', '#f032e6', '#bcf60c', '#008080', '#e6beff',
                '#9a6324', '#800000', '#aaffc3', '#808000', '#000075', '#808080')
set.seed(2)

if(n > length(col_vector)){
  
  col=sample(col_vector, n,replace = TRUE)
  
}else {
  
  col=sample(col_vector, n,replace = FALSE)
}

pal <- leaflet::colorFactor(pal = col, domain = unique(mtcars$carb))
```

Now simply I wanna draw this graph:

```
df <- dplyr::mutate(mtcars,
                colorCode = pal(mtcars[['carb']])
                )



highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(df, type = "scatter",
                hcaes(x = mpg, 
                      y = disp, 
                      group = carb
                ),
                color = unique(df$colorCode)

  )
```

It works with both points and legend but there is a strange behavior. If you check the `df` dataframe, you'll see that the color code for
`carb = 4` is `#F032E6` while the graph shows something different.Look at data frame below:
[image]

While the graph looks like this:
[image]

As you can see in the plot `carb = 4` is not `#F032E6`

defining the color inside `hcaes` works but the legend is not updated with same color palette.

```
n <- length(unique(mtcars$carb))

col_vector <- c('#e6194b', '#3cb44b', '#ffe119', '#4363d8', '#f58231', '#911eb4',
                '#46f0f0', '#f032e6', '#bcf60c', '#008080', '#e6beff',
                '#9a6324', '#800000', '#aaffc3', '#808000', '#000075', '#808080')
set.seed(2)

if(n > length(col_vector)){
  
  col=sample(col_vector, n,replace = TRUE)
  
}else {
  
  col=sample(col_vector, n,replace = FALSE)
}

pal <- leaflet::colorFactor(pal = col, domain = unique(mtcars$carb))

df <- dplyr::mutate(mtcars,
                    colorCode = pal(mtcars[['carb']])
                    )



highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(df, type = "scatter",
                hcaes(x = mpg, 
                      y = disp, 
                      group = carb,
                      color = colorCode
                      
                )
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `colour` in your aesthetics instead of `color` like this

```r
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(highcharter)

n <- length(unique(mtcars$cyl))

col_vector <- c('#e6194b', '#3cb44b', '#ffe119', '#4363d8', '#f58231', '#911eb4',
                         '#46f0f0', '#f032e6', '#bcf60c', '#008080', '#e6beff',
                         '#9a6324', '#800000', '#aaffc3', '#808000', '#000075', '#808080')
                         set.seed(2)
                         
                         if(n > length(col_vector)){
                           
                           col=sample(col_vector, n,replace = TRUE)
                           
                         }else {
                           
                           col=sample(col_vector, n,replace = FALSE)
                         }
                         
                         pal <- leaflet::colorFactor(pal = col, domain = unique(mtcars$cyl))
                         
                         df <- dplyr::mutate(mtcars,
                                             colorCode = pal(mtcars[['carb']])
                         )
                         
                         highchart() %>%
                           hc_add_series(df, type = "scatter",
                                         hcaes(x = mpg, 
                                               y = disp, 
                                               group = cyl,
                                               colour = colorCode))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: In the case we have 3 clusters from the mtcars dataframe ('cyl') . But it doesn't seem to work if you have more clusters. Try 'carb' instead of 'cyl' for example. It changes the point colors and the legend accordingly but it maps it wrong. compare with colorCode column on the dataframe.

* I update my question

Comment: Hi @YasinAmini, check my updated code! You should use `colour`. instead of `color`

Comment: Hi again. It still doesn't work. It doesn't use my costume color palette. it takes it from the default library values. The color codes are should be the same as the picture I posted in the question @Quinten